# Creating interaction sessions based on timestamps in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

I am trying to define which apps were used in different mobile usage sessions. Basically, a session is a series of actions by a
single user made within a small range of time (aka. session delta). In other words, if no interaction happens within 5 minutes of the previous
interaction, a user’s session is deemed closed. The next
interaction is considered a separate session. I would like to know how many mobile sessions are there in the dataset. Also, I would like to know which apps were launched in each session.
All the rows in my data frame are time stamped.
Here is an example from the dataset:

```
        timestamp               App
6784    2018-04-08 14:31:29.209 Google
6785    2018-04-08 14:58:42.875 Google
6786    2018-04-08 18:18:04.757 Chrome
6787    2018-04-08 21:08:41.368 Google
6788    2018-04-11 10:53:10.744 Google
6789    2018-04-14 19:54:37.441 Google
6790    2018-04-14 19:54:59.833 Google
6791    2018-04-14 19:55:10.844 YouTube
6792    2018-04-14 19:55:34.486 Google
6793    2018-04-14 20:23:00.315 Google
6794    2018-04-15 08:23:44.873 Google
6795    2018-04-15 08:24:07.257 Google
6796    2018-04-16 16:42:35.538 Google
6797    2018-04-16 16:42:48.351 Google
6798    2018-04-17 08:10:54.734 Google
6799    2018-04-17 08:13:28.855 Google
6800    2018-04-17 08:16:49.408 Google
6801    2018-04-17 08:18:55.049 Google
6802    2018-04-17 08:21:04.201 Google
6803    2018-04-17 08:26:14.254 Google
```

And this is the desired output:

```
        timestamp               App         SessionID
6784    2018-04-08 14:31:29.209 Google      1
6785    2018-04-08 14:58:42.875 Google      2
6786    2018-04-08 18:18:04.757 Chrome      3
6787    2018-04-08 21:08:41.368 Google      4
6788    2018-04-11 10:53:10.744 Google      5
6789    2018-04-14 19:54:37.441 Google      6
6790    2018-04-14 19:54:59.833 Google      6
6791    2018-04-14 19:55:10.844 YouTube     6
6792    2018-04-14 19:55:34.486 Google      6
6793    2018-04-14 20:23:00.315 Google      7
6794    2018-04-15 08:23:44.873 Google      8
6795    2018-04-15 08:24:07.257 Google      8
6796    2018-04-16 16:42:35.538 Google      9
6797    2018-04-16 16:42:48.351 Google      9
6798    2018-04-17 08:10:54.734 Google      10
6799    2018-04-17 08:13:28.855 Google      10
6800    2018-04-17 08:16:49.408 Google      10
6801    2018-04-17 08:18:55.049 Google      10
6802    2018-04-17 08:21:04.201 Google      10
6803    2018-04-17 08:26:14.254 Google      11
```

Comment: @AntonvBR Here it is in case you haven't spotted it. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, now I understood the problem. But I can also see someone posted an answer! It looks correct and I upvoted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want `.shift` + `.cumsum()`

The `+1` is because your first row will always be `NaT` for the difference, which evaluates to `False` for the comparison, which will always start the `SessionID` from 0 otherwise.

```
import pandas as pd
df['SessionID'] = (df.timestamp-df.timestamp.shift(1) > pd.Timedelta(5, 'm')).cumsum()+1

                   timestamp      App  SessionID
6784 2018-04-08 14:31:29.209   Google          1
6785 2018-04-08 14:58:42.875   Google          2
6786 2018-04-08 18:18:04.757   Chrome          3
6787 2018-04-08 21:08:41.368   Google          4
6788 2018-04-11 10:53:10.744   Google          5
6789 2018-04-14 19:54:37.441   Google          6
6790 2018-04-14 19:54:59.833   Google          6
6791 2018-04-14 19:55:10.844  YouTube          6
6792 2018-04-14 19:55:34.486   Google          6
6793 2018-04-14 20:23:00.315   Google          7
6794 2018-04-15 08:23:44.873   Google          8
6795 2018-04-15 08:24:07.257   Google          8
6796 2018-04-16 16:42:35.538   Google          9
6797 2018-04-16 16:42:48.351   Google          9
6798 2018-04-17 08:10:54.734   Google         10
6799 2018-04-17 08:13:28.855   Google         10
6800 2018-04-17 08:16:49.408   Google         10
6801 2018-04-17 08:18:55.049   Google         10
6802 2018-04-17 08:21:04.201   Google         10
6803 2018-04-17 08:26:14.254   Google         11
```

If you also have `UserID` you can then implement logic where you increment the ID when either the time is greater than 5 minutes, OR the `userID` changes. That is accomplished by:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
1,2018-04-08T09:48:17.573,YouTube
1,2018-04-08T09:47:57.849,Chrome
1,2018-04-08T09:48:28.538,Instagram
1,2018-04-08T09:48:37.381,Maps
2,2018-04-08T09:48:46.680,Netflix
2,2018-04-08T09:48:56.672,Google Play Store
1,2018-04-08T09:56:58.880,Google
1,2018-04-08T09:57:25.461,DB Navigator
1,2018-04-08T11:28:38.762,Google
1,2018-04-08T12:58:31.455,Google
1,2018-04-08T14:31:18.131,Google
1,2018-04-08T14:31:29.209,Google
1,2018-04-08T14:58:42.875,Google
1,2018-04-08T18:18:04.757,Chrome
1,2018-04-08T21:08:41.368,Google
1,2018-04-11T10:53:10.744,Google
1,2018-04-14T19:54:37.441,Google
1,2018-04-14T19:54:59.833,Google
1,2018-04-14T19:55:10.844,YouTube
1,2018-04-14T19:55:34.486,Google
1,2018-04-14T20:23:00.315,Google
2,2018-04-15T08:23:44.873,Google
2,2018-04-15T08:24:07.257,Google'''

df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(data), names=['userID','timestamp','App'], 
                 parse_dates=[1])

df.sort_values(by=['userID','timestamp'], inplace=True)

cond1 = df.timestamp-df.timestamp.shift(1) > pd.Timedelta(5, 'm')
cond2 = df.userID != df.userID.shift(1)
df['SessionID'] = (cond1|cond2).cumsum()
```

Returns:

```
    userID               timestamp                App  SessionID
1        1 2018-04-08 09:47:57.849             Chrome          1
0        1 2018-04-08 09:48:17.573            YouTube          1
2        1 2018-04-08 09:48:28.538          Instagram          1
3        1 2018-04-08 09:48:37.381               Maps          1
6        1 2018-04-08 09:56:58.880             Google          2
7        1 2018-04-08 09:57:25.461       DB Navigator          2
8        1 2018-04-08 11:28:38.762             Google          3
9        1 2018-04-08 12:58:31.455             Google          4
10       1 2018-04-08 14:31:18.131             Google          5
11       1 2018-04-08 14:31:29.209             Google          5
12       1 2018-04-08 14:58:42.875             Google          6
13       1 2018-04-08 18:18:04.757             Chrome          7
14       1 2018-04-08 21:08:41.368             Google          8
15       1 2018-04-11 10:53:10.744             Google          9
16       1 2018-04-14 19:54:37.441             Google         10
17       1 2018-04-14 19:54:59.833             Google         10
18       1 2018-04-14 19:55:10.844            YouTube         10
19       1 2018-04-14 19:55:34.486             Google         10
20       1 2018-04-14 20:23:00.315             Google         11
4        2 2018-04-08 09:48:46.680            Netflix         12
5        2 2018-04-08 09:48:56.672  Google Play Store         12
21       2 2018-04-15 08:23:44.873             Google         13
22       2 2018-04-15 08:24:07.257             Google         13
```

Comment: Thank you. How would you approach it if the dataset also had a userid column? Right now, I am sorting the columns by userid and timestamp. But, the latest row of a user is considered in the same session as the earliest row of the next user.

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. I tried this but it seems that the session ID becomes user-dependent (starts from 1 for each user).

Comment: @Moh, yeah I understand what you want now. What do your `userIDs` look like? One simple option is to just create a new `sessionID` by combining the `userID` and user-dependent session-ID. But this can be problematic depending upon the range of `userIDs`. But if they are all always 10 digit identifiers then you can safely do something like `df.userID.astype(str) + df.sessionID.astype(str)` to create a new unique sessionID

Comment: A typical userID looks like this: user891344957eed20ab
Right, your solution sounds quite good.

Comment: Actually, I'll have a better solution in a minute. Just let me check it

Comment: Works like a charm.

Comment: What happened to the answer?

Comment: @AntonvBR @Moh  Sorry, I thought there was an error because things didn't match and then realized I had just changed one of the dates. It's all fine now with the correct initial `df`

Comment: @ALollz I updated your answer to be more readable. Good job I'd say!

Answer (score 2):

There might be something more effective than this but you could get the value counts like this:

(after you have the SessionID that is)

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)
for k,v in df.groupby('SessionID')['App'].value_counts().items():
    d[k[0]].update({k[1]:v})
```

d

```
{1: {'Chrome': 1, 'Instagram': 1, 'Maps': 1, 'Netflix': 1, 'YouTube': 1},
 2: {'Google': 1, 'Google Play Store': 1},
 3: {'DB Navigator': 1},
 4: {'Google': 1},
 5: {'Google': 2},
 6: {'Google': 1},
 7: {'Google': 1},
 8: {'Chrome': 1},
 9: {'Google': 1},
 10: {'Google': 3, 'YouTube': 1},
 11: {'Google': 1},
 12: {'Google': 3}}
```

The sum you can get by:

```
df.groupby('SessionID')['App'].count().sum()  # 23
```

Comment: @Moh You asked for "I would like to know how many mobile sessions are there in the dataset. Also, I would like to know which apps were launched in each session." Or do you want another format?

Comment: Ah yes, I got it now. Thanks.