# Identifying sessions over arbitrary time period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a set of data that I need to group by user_id and 72-hour sessions. However, the only data I have available currently is the timestamp for each page a user visited on a site.

The number of visits a user makes is not consistent, so I need to shift based on the amount of elapsed time between user visits. Example:

```py
user_id timestamp
1   2020-08-27 21:05:55.770
1   2020-08-29 17:17:04.558
1   2020-09-02 00:37:54.627
1   2020-09-03 17:36:25.267
1   2020-09-04 09:43:05.010
1   2020-09-07 21:07:55.488
1   2020-09-09 18:05:34.420
1   2020-09-11 00:13:33.861
1   2020-09-12 19:31:45.936
1   2020-09-15 03:43:35.287
1   2020-09-20 00:12:20.337
1   2020-09-21 13:29:51.342
2   2020-09-01 06:46:03.722
2   2020-09-02 01:16:02.315
2   2020-09-03 08:58:44.665
2   2020-09-04 00:24:25.201
2   2020-09-05 02:42:32.207
2   2020-09-17 22:17:09.320
2   2020-09-18 02:55:53.522
```

My desired output is:

```py
user_id timestamp           session_id
1   2020-08-27 21:05:55.770 1
1   2020-08-29 17:17:04.558 1
1   2020-09-02 00:37:54.627 2 <---more than 72-hours since first visit on 8/27
1   2020-09-03 17:36:25.267 2
1   2020-09-04 09:43:05.010 2
1   2020-09-07 21:07:55.488 3 <---more than 72-hours since 09/02 visit
1   2020-09-09 18:05:34.420 3
1   2020-09-11 00:13:33.861 4
1   2020-09-12 19:31:45.936 4
1   2020-09-15 03:43:35.287 5
1   2020-09-20 00:12:20.337 6
1   2020-09-21 13:29:51.342 6
2   2020-09-01 06:46:03.722 1
2   2020-09-02 01:16:02.315 1
2   2020-09-03 08:58:44.665 1
2   2020-09-04 00:24:25.201 2
2   2020-09-05 02:42:32.207 2
2   2020-09-17 22:17:09.320 3
2   2020-09-18 02:55:53.522 3
```

However, all examples I've found have only compared against the previous row. I believe I need to use some sort of `.cumsum()` combined with a `shift()` to generate sessions, but so far I've only been able to see if the session was within 72-hours of the previous row, not since the previous session.

Some things I've tried:

```python
g = df.groupby('dotcom_id')
df['session_number'] = g['visited_time'].apply(lambda s: (s - s.shift(1) > pd.to_timedelta(72, unit='hour')).fillna(0).cumsum(skipna=False))
```

This only generate 2 sessions for `user_id=2` in the above dataframe, incrementing the `session_id` between 09/05 and 09/17.

I then attempted this from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311201/creating-interaction-sessions-based-on-timestamps-in-pandas)

```python
cond1 = (df.visited_time-df.visited_time.shift(1)).cumsum() > pd.Timedelta(72, 'h')
cond2 = df.user_id == df.user_id.shift(1)
df['session_number'] = (cond1 & cond2).cumsum()
```

This generate a new session ID for every row for `user_id=2`. I'm not understanding how I can get the `cumsum()` to reset every time a new session has started.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could help:

```
def calc_cumsum(pdf):
    pdf.sort_values(by=['Date'], inplace=True, ascending=True)
    cumsums = []
    prev = 0
    reset = False
    for v in pdf['Difference_between_last_timestamp'].values:
        if prev is None:
            cumsums.append(v)
            prev = v
        else:
            prev = prev + v if not reset else v
            cumsums.append(prev)
            reset = True if prev >= amount_in_sec else False
            
    pdf['cumsum'] = cumsums
    return pdf
```

not efficient, but could work : D