# Find timedeltas in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, coding-efficiency

I have a pandas dataframe containing 400 individual measurements. Each mesurment is a time series composed of roughly 1000 rows. The whole dataframe therefore contains roughly 400.000 rows. The index of the dataframe is a timestamp.

For ease of use I would like to assign each of the 400 measurements an ID as a new column so that I can easily query the rows beloning to each ID by: `df[df["ID"] == certain_id]`. Currently I loop through every row of the dataframe and read the timestamp. I then compare it to the timestamp of the next row and if the difference reaches a certain threshold I know, that a new measurement series has startet:

```
t_0 = df.index[0] # very first timestamp
id = 1 # first ID

df.loc[df.index[0], "ID"] = 1

for row in df_raw.itertuples():
   try:
      t_1 = row.Index
   except IndexError:
      break
   if t_1 >= t_0 + pd.to_timedelta(min_diff): # Check for threshold
      df.loc[row.Index, "ID"] = id
      id += 1
      t_0 = t_1
      continue
   else:
      df.loc[row.Index, "ID"] = id
      t_0 = t_1
```

This works fine but takes ages to assign all IDs. How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: You're looking for sessionization of your records. Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50311201/creating-interaction-sessions-based-on-timestamps-in-pandas answer your question?

Comment: This seems very promising! I´ll implement the solution and will let you know. Thanks a lot @ozacha!